# How to make responsive layout for large screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I use constraint layout for design in my app and set `wrap_content` or `match_parent` for width and height. When App run in tablets or large screen size, The size of the views is getting smaller. Is another way to make the views bigger without creating another layout for large screens?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_heart" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_count_result_search_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red_400"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="65"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Tablets]

[image: Phones]

Comment: If you want to keep the same ratio between different resolution, you can consider to use `GuildLine` with percent to resolve this.

Comment: Try this documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: @KalanaChinthaka it says I should create another layout for tablets.

Answer (score -1):

If you want full view then you have to use **match_parent** for width and height